# Why is this regex not working properly?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have this regex: `^\/\*` to check and see if a file contains those two characters at the beginning. I'm iterating over many c++ source files trying to see which of them contain that. The problem is, that if a file contains this:

```
#include <source.h>

/* this is a comment */
```

this also matches the regex. I don't understand why, as the regex doesn't have the multiline flag on.

Here's the code for the regex:

```
multi = /^\/\*/
```

Why isn't this matching only at the beginning of the text? Here's basically everything I'm doing:

```
data = File.read(filename)
if data =~ multi
   puts "file starts with multiline header"
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Ruby `^` matches after every newline.  Use `\A` to match only at the start of the entire string:

```
multi = /\A\/\*/
```

Comment: This kind of sux. Is this Ruby only behaviour, or do all the languages have this?

Comment: Most languages have a switch called "multiline mode" that causes them to behave like this, but Ruby is the only one I know that does it by default.  Perl's multiline mode looks like `/^test/m`

Answer (score 3):

Use `\A` (beginning of string) instead of `^` (beginning of line).

The interpretation of `^` is not completely consistent between flavors. Sometimes you need to set a mode modifier for multi-line strings, but not always. `\A` is consistent (although not available in all flavors, but most of them. Exceptions are XML, POSIX ERE/BREs and a few others).

Comment: Is this the same in Perl/Python?

Comment: In Perl/Python, behaviour of `^` depends on the mode modifiers used (`/m` in Perl or `re.MULTILINE` in Python).

Answer (score 1):

Why use a regular expression?

```
multi = "/*"
data = File.read(filename)
if data[0..2] == multi
   puts "file starts with multiline header"
end
```

Comment: Because additional spaces may be present before the comment start. The regex was just to find out why Ruby behaved like that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of ruby internals, but try this:

/^[^a-zA-Z#<>]/*/

The first part ensures that any valid character is not found before your multiline comment.
Please, note that [^a-zA-Z#<>] is just an example, you should complete it with a valid combination.